# SQL WHERE none of the joined records in the table match certain criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one Table

Table1

| ID |
| --- |
| Cat |
| Dog |
| Rabbit |

And another Table

Table2

| ID | Action |
| --- | --- |
| Cat | Eat |
| Cat | Sleep |
| Cat | Poop |
| Dog | Eat |
| Dog | Sleep |
| Rabbit | Eat |

I want to find which animal hasn't slept - but when I join table1 on table2 where ID = ID and filter for when the action <> 'Sleep' I still get a record for Rabbit because Sleep <> Eat.

I want to join table1 on table2 and look at all of the records in the join, and if none of the records = Sleep, then return the ID.

If we were looking for no Sleep I want to return Rabbit, and no Poop to return Dog & Rabbit

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Zaki Sql Server Management Studio 2016

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: @Zaki *Sql Server Management Studio* is not the RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need a `not exists` criteria, try the following

```
select id
from table1 t1
where not exists (
  select * from table2 t2 
  where t2.id = t1.id and t2.action = 'sleep'
);
```

Comment: That's the answer !  Thank you